# Driver for proper HD-playback using ATI FirePro M5800

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, hp, hd-video

I have a HP 8540w notebook with a ATI FirePro M5800 graphic card and have tried several drivers: the default one, the proprietary one (available through the additional driver dialog) and ati-driver-installer-11-8-x86.x86_64, but all them seem to have real difficulties playing hd-videos without any stuttering. Also, hd-video playback does work well on Windows 7.
What driver should I use? It seems my graphics card is a pretty rare one.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!